# Link buttons in a cell to the proper view (proper tag) when sorted alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view that displays list of clients (logo of a client + name etc) and at the same time I created 4 buttons that link to specific information about each client (such as overview and such).

Everything works properly when clicking on these buttons and I am taken to the proper corresponding `viewui` info.

Now the problem is when I sort everything alphabetically. Everything gets sorted properly (company names and such) except the buttons still link to the previous `indexPath.row` order...
So when I click on client one in the alpha list I see the information of the first client which is correct,., now if I click on the first client under the letter B... I see the information of first client in list A... so the indexpath of the buttons is not sorted at all....

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSIndexPath *offsetPath = [self modelRowIndexForIndexPath:indexPath];
        //NSLog(@"Requested: %@  --  Off: %@",indexPath,offsetPath);



    RMCustomClientCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ClientCell"];

    RMClients *client;

    if(!self.alphaMode){


        client = [self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {

        NSString *key = [self.alphaKeys objectAtIndex:offsetPath.section];
        NSArray *specificClients = [self.sortedClients objectForKey:key];
        client = [specificClients objectAtIndex:offsetPath.row];


    }


cell.extraDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.overviewDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.listDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.eventsDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;


    cell.nameLabel.text = client.name;


    return cell;

}
```

Now how do I correct this `cell.extraDetailsButton.tag = indexPath.row;` (the indexPath.row) should be replaced by something else, right?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be set to `offsetPath.row` instead?  Isn't that the index you're referring to in order to get the `client` object?

Answer (score 0):

Doing offsets and such for each `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is inefficient and prone to error (as you have found out). Instead, when your change the sort method on your tableview, change the sort of self.clients *so your indexes always match your tables*. If you do that, you can simplify your button logic quite a bit as follows:

Define 4 tags for your buttons.

```
#define BUTTON0_TAG 100
#define BUTTON1_TAG 101
#define BUTTON2_TAG 102
#define BUTTON3_TAG 103
```

Bind your buttons to this method:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    switch (sender.tag) {
       case BUTTON0_TAG:
          [self detailsForClientAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          break;
       case BUTTON1_TAG:
          [self overviewForClientAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          break;
       case BUTTON2_TAG:
          [self listForClientAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          break;
       case BUTTON3_TAG:
          [self eventsForClientAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this is happening,, I still can't get it to work?

Comment: @user1830684 No idea. The code I supplied works fine. If it's helped please upvote and/or mark it as accepted. If you are having additional issues you might want to ask a new SO question.

Comment: Ok,, How do you bind your buttons to this method? Thanks agian you have been very helpful...